# PHP MYSQL: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching already 2 days for the error but i cant find out what's wrong. I hope that somebody can help me here.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Patient ( patients_ID, height, nameOfTheFamilyDoctor,
    nameOfTheHealthInsurance, weight, birthDate, station, room  ) VALUES 
    ( :patient, :height, :nameOfTheFamilyDoctor,
    :nameOfTheHealthInsurance, :weight, :birthDate, :station, :room) ";

    //Again, we need to update our tokens with the actual data:

    if (ctype_digit($_POST['height']) && ctype_digit($_POST['weight'])) {

        $query_params = array(

            ':patient' => $_POST['patientsID'],
            ':height' => $_POST['height'],
            ':nameOfTheFamilyDoctor' => $_POST['nameOfTheFamilyDoctor'],
            ':nameOfTheHealthInsurance' => $_POST['nameOfTheHealthInsurance'],
            ':weight' => $_POST['weight'],
            ':birthDate' => $_POST['birthDate'],
            ':station' => $_POST['station'],
            ':room' => $_POST['room'],
        );
    }

    //time to run our query, and create the user
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!" . $ex->getMessage();;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
```

I am getting this error message:

> {"success":0,"message":"Database Error2. Please Try Again!SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"}`

I have checked all variables for spelling errors, etc.

Thanks for all you help.

Comment: You'll get that error for sure when `height` or `weight` don't pass the `ctype_digit` validation.

Comment: Isn't it weird that creating $query_params is in condition, but executing the query requiring those params is not?

Comment: Put your try/catch inside of your if statement, or else the query will try to run without bound variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['height']` and `$_POST['weight']` is going to be a string. Try using `is_numeric` instead of `ctype_digit`. You can convert to an integer via `intval` if necessary.

`var_dump($query_params)` before your try/catch block... see if it even exists outside of your `if()` statement. You will see that it's null.

Lastly, you need to rethink your logic... what happens if your `if()` statement fails? Does it make sense to continue the query? In that case, your try/catch should be in `if()` statement... Then, you should create an `else` to handle errors. (alternatively, you could throw an error and have an error handler elsewhere).